# In Laravel 8, how to copy a file from one disk to another using Storage?

Tags: laravel, storage

In `config\filesystems.php` a disk is configured (this is a properly connected VPS.) I call it `vps_disk`. In the following way I can get the file:

```
$file = Storage::disk('vps_disk')->get('/path/to/file');
```

The problem is that I can't save then this file on the local disk (changing its name moreover). I try unsuccessfully in this way:

```
$save_file = $file->storeAs('/', $filename, 'local_disk');
```

And that's the error I get:

```
Call to a member function storeAs() on string
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files

Comment: @Pradeep Thanks for the reply but I can't. Can you be more explicit please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following line of code properly returns the contents of the file:

```
$content = Storage::disk('vps_disk')->get('/path/to/file');
```

And here is the way to save the file to the local disk:

```
Storage::put('path/to/file/'.$filename_with_extension, $content);
```

Comment: This is copying the contents and then saving them into a file. Won't be very efficient or performant. This would be especially bad if you're trying to copy files from one s3 bucket to another.